# Debian + xfce multidisplay flickering

Tags: debian, multiple-monitors, xfce4

I use Debian 9 with xfce (v 4.12) on lenovo l450 and two dell external displays: one connected with VGA and other one with mini-dp.

Here is info about videocard:

```
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)  (0x1616)
    Version: 13.0.6
    Accelerated: yes
```

And the issue with that displays that they are flickering - it switches off for a second or two and then switches on. I found out that mini-dp display usually flickers when I move cursor from it to some other display. Second external display (VGA) do not switches of and have any issues at all, until I disconnect mini-dp display. Than it sometimes got flickering like moving right-left, right-left. The same issue a git once with embedded display.

What I already tried:

1) Install all debian system updates.

2) Install Intel videodrivers from backports.

3) Tried to install Cinnamon and use it instead of xfce.

Nothing has changed.

I supposed that it is an xfce issue, since it shows weird behaivior when I re-connect display cables: xfce enables display mirroring while checkbox "mirror displays" is off, and I have to enable it, save changes, that disable it and save changes. After it mirroring is disabled. And also xfce uses mini-dp display as primary and ignores that fact that settings says that primari display is laptops embedded display. So I suppose I hit this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-panel/+bug/1596751

I suppose that since flickering usually triggered by cursor actions, something is wrong on the level between desktop environment (since cinnamon has shows that issue too) and videodriver. But I has no so strong knowledge of linux so I have no idea wich subsystem could cause this effects.

So the question is: which side showld I digg to solve this issue?